# How to get RGB components from Color in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, colors, rgb, swiftui

If I have a SwiftUI `Color`:

```
let col: Color = Color(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5)
```

How do I get the RGB components from `col`?

Like this maybe:

```
print(col.components.red)
```

In UIKit, I could use `UIColor.getRed` but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent in SwiftUI.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

## iOS 17/ macOS 14 (advanced but native)

You can ask for resolving `Color` components **in the given environment**, because colors are different in different environments (for example in dark and light environments). In the following sample, I resolved it using the current environment of the used color.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.self) var environment
    @State private var color = Color.red
    @State private var components: Color.Resolved?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ColorPicker("Select your favorite color", selection: $color)

            if let components {
                Text("R: \(components.red)")
                Text("G: \(components.green)")
                Text("B: \(components.blue)")
                Text("A: \(components.opacity)")
                Text("HEX: \(components.description)")
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .onChange(of: color, initial: true) { components = color.resolve(in: environment) }
    }
}
```

<sub>The code above has been written for iOS 17 beta 1 using Xcode 15 beta 1</sub>

---

## iOS 14 / macOS 10.16

There is a new initializer that takes a `Color` and returns a `UIColor` for **iOS** or `NSColor` for **macOS** now. With the help of those you can implement the following extensions:

```
import SwiftUI

#if canImport(UIKit)
import UIKit
#elseif canImport(AppKit)
import AppKit
#endif

extension Color {
    var components: (red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, opacity: CGFloat) {

        #if canImport(UIKit)
        typealias NativeColor = UIColor
        #elseif canImport(AppKit)
        typealias NativeColor = NSColor
        #endif

        var r: CGFloat = 0
        var g: CGFloat = 0
        var b: CGFloat = 0
        var o: CGFloat = 0

        guard NativeColor(self).getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &o) else {
            // You can handle the failure here as you want
            return (0, 0, 0, 0)
        }

        return (r, g, b, o)
    }

    var hex: String {
        String(
            format: "#%02x%02x%02x%02x",
            Int(components.red * 255),
            Int(components.green * 255),
            Int(components.blue * 255),
            Int(components.opacity * 255)
        )
    }
}
```

---

## Usage

```
Color.red.components.red // 0.9999999403953552 // <- SwiftUI Colors are not pure!
```

Comment: I found that this somehow loses the dark appearance set in assets?

Comment: I've managed to fix this, see answer below. Would be too much for an edit.

Comment: If you are using ColorPicker on macOS, you should use NativeColor(self).usingColorSpace(NSColorSpace.extendedSRGB)?.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &o) or else dynamic colors will cause a crash.

Comment: This solution is almost great, but there is one thing you should improve. the hex property doesn't give the same value as the original one. To get the correct values, you should use the round for every colour component. eg.: Int(round(components.green * 255))...

Answer (score 14):

Simple one-liner:

```
print(UIColor(Color.blue).cgColor.components)
```

You get an `[CGFloat]?` of [red, green, blue, alpha].

**Update**

Use `NSColor` for macOS

Comment: Best answer and simple!

Comment: works only on iOS. What about macOS ?

Comment: NSColor instead of UIColor

Answer (score 6):

Waiting for an API I've abused `CustomStringConvertible` protocol for the simple rgba case where the color description format is #rrggbbaa

```
debugPrint(Color.red)
debugPrint(Color(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0))
debugPrint(Color(red: 1.0, green: 0.3, blue: 0.0))
debugPrint(Color(.sRGB, red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.5, opacity: 0.3))
debugPrint(Color(hue: 1.0, saturation: 0.0, brightness: 1.0))
debugPrint(Color(.displayP3, red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, opacity: 1.0).description)

red
#FF0000FF
#FF4C00FF
#FF00804D
#FFFFFFFF
"DisplayP3(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, opacity: 1.0)"
```

as you can see, things like Color.red just dump "red" but if you are working with 
simple RGB colors generated by code (ie from a color picker) then this is not too bad

```
extension SwiftUI.Color {
    var redComponent: Double? {
        let val = description
        guard val.hasPrefix("#") else { return nil }
        let r1 = val.index(val.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
        let r2 = val.index(val.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)
        return Double(Int(val[r1...r2], radix: 16)!) / 255.0
    }

    var greenComponent: Double? {
        let val = description
        guard val.hasPrefix("#") else { return nil }
        let g1 = val.index(val.startIndex, offsetBy: 3)
        let g2 = val.index(val.startIndex, offsetBy: 4)
        return Double(Int(val[g1...g2], radix: 16)!) / 255.0
    }

    var blueComponent: Double? {
        let val = description
        guard val.hasPrefix("#") else { return nil }
        let b1 = val.index(val.startIndex, offsetBy: 5)
        let b2 = val.index(val.startIndex, offsetBy: 6)
        return Double(Int(val[b1...b2], radix: 16)!) / 255.0
    }

    var opacityComponent: Double? {
        let val = description
        guard val.hasPrefix("#") else { return nil }
        let b1 = val.index(val.startIndex, offsetBy: 7)
        let b2 = val.index(val.startIndex, offsetBy: 8)
        return Double(Int(val[b1...b2], radix: 16)!) / 255.0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have found that @Mojtaba Hosseinis answer is working fine, except when you have your colors declared inside assets with light and dark appearances.

Then I found that the dark appearance somehow gets lost when using `UIColor(self)`. Here is a workaround I came up with:

Note, this is only for `iOS` since my app is `iOS` only, you could of course do the same as @Mojtaba Hosseini and adapt it to `macOS` as well.

```
extension Color {

    var components: (r: Double, g: Double, b: Double, o: Double)? {
        let uiColor: UIColor
        
        var r: CGFloat = 0
        var g: CGFloat = 0
        var b: CGFloat = 0
        var o: CGFloat = 0
        
        if self.description.contains("NamedColor") {
            let lowerBound = self.description.range(of: "name: \"")!.upperBound
            let upperBound = self.description.range(of: "\", bundle")!.lowerBound
            let assetsName = String(self.description[lowerBound..<upperBound])
            
            uiColor = UIColor(named: assetsName)!
        } else {
            uiColor = UIColor(self)
        }

        guard uiColor.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &o) else { return nil }
        
        return (Double(r), Double(g), Double(b), Double(o))
    }
}
```

The idea is to use the `UIColor(named:)` initializer instead, where all appearances are correct.
Fortunately, the name we set in assets is saved in the description of the `Color`. We only have to abstract it since there is also other information, namely bundle, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Mojtaba's answer, I came up with a shorter, more flexible version:

```
#if canImport(UIKit)
import UIKit
#elseif canImport(AppKit)
import AppKit
#endif

extension Color {
    #if canImport(UIKit)
    var asNative: UIColor { UIColor(self) }
    #elseif canImport(AppKit)
    var asNative: NSColor { NSColor(self) }
    #endif

    var rgba: (red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat) {
        let color = asNative.usingColorSpace(.deviceRGB)!
        var t = (CGFloat(), CGFloat(), CGFloat(), CGFloat())
        color.getRed(&t.0, green: &t.1, blue: &t.2, alpha: &t.3)
        return t
    }

    var hsva: (hue: CGFloat, saturation: CGFloat, value: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat) {
        let color = asNative.usingColorSpace(.deviceRGB)!
        var t = (CGFloat(), CGFloat(), CGFloat(), CGFloat())
        color.getHue(&t.0, saturation: &t.1, brightness: &t.2, alpha: &t.3)
        return t
    }
}
```

Doing asNative.redComponent etc. might also work, FYI.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **no** - there's no API do so (yet), but...

Most of SwiftUI structs have fields that are `private`, like in `Color`.

You can use `Mirror` to extract such informations - but keep in mind it is not efficient.

Here's how to extract the hexadecimal representation of a SwiftUI `Color` - for educational purpose.

Copy and paste this into a **Xcode 11** playground.

```swift
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

let systemColor = Color.red
let color = Color(red: 0.3, green: 0.5, blue: 1)

extension Color {

    var hexRepresentation: String? {
        let children = Mirror(reflecting: color).children
        let _provider = children.filter { $0.label == "provider" }.first
        guard let provider = _provider?.value else {
            return nil
        }
        let providerChildren = Mirror(reflecting: provider).children
        let _base = providerChildren.filter { $0.label == "base" }.first
        guard let base = _base?.value else {
            return nil
        }
        var baseValue: String = ""
        dump(base, to: &baseValue)
        guard let firstLine = baseValue.split(separator: "\n").first,
              let hexString = firstLine.split(separator: " ")[1] as Substring? else {
            return nil
        }
        return hexString.trimmingCharacters(in: .newlines)
    }

}

systemColor.hexRepresentation
color.hexRepresentation
```

Colors like `.red`, `.white`, etc., don't seem to have many information in them, when `dumped`.

Just their "system" name.

```
▿ red
  ▿ provider: SwiftUI.(unknown context at $1297483bc).ColorBox<SwiftUI.SystemColorType> #0
    - super: SwiftUI.(unknown context at $129748300).AnyColorBox
    - base: SwiftUI.SystemColorType.red
```

A `Color` instantiated with `red`/`blue`/`green` components does instead.

```
▿ #4C80FFFF
  ▿ provider: SwiftUI.(unknown context at $11cd2e3bc).ColorBox<SwiftUI.Color._Resolved> #0
    - super: SwiftUI.(unknown context at $11cd2e300).AnyColorBox
    ▿ base: #4C80FFFF
      - linearRed: 0.073238954
      - linearGreen: 0.21404114
      - linearBlue: 1.0
      - opacity: 1.0
```

In the Playground, you will see:

- `systemColor.hexRepresentation` returning `nil`
- `color.hexRepresentation` returning `"#4C80FFFF"`

Comment: I feel like the answer to this question should be “you don’t”. Data flow in SwiftUI goes from the data into the views. You don’t get data out of the views. You put data into the views. If you have a colour then it only exists because you gave it the rgb values. So you already have the data.

Comment: @Fogmeister Good point - but it's always good fun digging into private implementations :)

Comment: Hehe nice find :)

Comment: @Fogmeister I agree with the general sentiment, but how would you suggest I store color in my code? Say I have a model for a "Page" that has a background color. Should I create my own Color struct, then convert to SwiftUI color in the view? This seems like something a framework should provide...

Answer (score 1):

You can use UIColor and transform the UIColor to Color after.
Code:

```
extension UIColor {
    func hexValue() -> String {
        let values = self.cgColor.components
        var outputR: Int = 0
        var outputG: Int = 0
        var outputB: Int = 0
        var outputA: Int = 1

        switch values!.count {
            case 1:
                outputR = Int(values![0] * 255)
                outputG = Int(values![0] * 255)
                outputB = Int(values![0] * 255)
                outputA = 1
            case 2:
                outputR = Int(values![0] * 255)
                outputG = Int(values![0] * 255)
                outputB = Int(values![0] * 255)
                outputA = Int(values![1] * 255)
            case 3:
                outputR = Int(values![0] * 255)
                outputG = Int(values![1] * 255)
                outputB = Int(values![2] * 255)
                outputA = 1
            case 4:
                outputR = Int(values![0] * 255)
                outputG = Int(values![1] * 255)
                outputB = Int(values![2] * 255)
                outputA = Int(values![3] * 255)
            default:
                break
        }
        return "#" + String(format:"%02X", outputR) + String(format:"%02X", outputG) + String(format:"%02X", outputB) + String(format:"%02X", outputA)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For MacOS 14.X Sonoma**

```
func getRgbInfo(of color : Color) -> String {
    
    // 1: convert SwiftUI.Color into NSColor with RGB colorspace
    guard let nsColor: NSColor = NSColor(color).usingColorSpace(.sRGB) else { return "Error" }
    
    // 2: create variables to be filled
    var red   : CGFloat = 0
    var green : CGFloat = 0
    var blue  : CGFloat = 0
    var alpha : CGFloat = 0
    
    // 3: fill the variables
    nsColor.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)
    
    // 4: optional : Create Integer values
    let redValue   : Int = Int(red * 255)
    let greenValue : Int = Int(green * 255)
    let blueValue  : Int = Int(blue * 255)
    
    // 5: return the result
    return "(R: \(redValue), G: \(greenValue), B: \(blueValue), A: \(alpha)"
}
```

Comment: This answer basically repeats information shown in other answers.

Comment: @HangarRash: Yes it seems so, but I got some errors using the other samples of solutions. For me - in an macOS dev environment - it turns out, that the small addition (usingColorSpace(.sRGB) made this all run. Thats why I posted my answer ... well, I probably should have posted only the "additional" part.

Comment: Updating your answer with an explanation of what makes your answer useful compared to the others like it would make it much better.