# How can I change a SwiftUI Color to UIColor?

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui

I'm trying to change a SwiftUI Color to an instance of UIColor.

I can easily get the RGBA from the UIColor, but I don't know how to get the "Color" instance to return the corresponding RGB and opacity values.

```
@EnvironmentObject var colorStore: ColorStore

init() {
    let red =     //get red value from colorStore.primaryThemeColor
    let green = //get green value from colorStore.primaryThemeColor
    let blue =   //get blue value from colorStore.primaryThemeColor
    let alpha = //get alpha value from colorStore.primaryThemeColor
    
    let color = UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = color
}
```

...or maybe there is a better way to accomplish what I am looking for?

Answer (score 126):

### SwiftUI 2.0

There is a new initializer that takes a `Color` and returns a `UIColor` for **iOS** or `NSColor` for **macOS** now. So:

#### iOS

```
UIColor(Color.red)
```

---

#### macOS

```
NSColor(Color.red)
```

---

#### Core Graphics

```
UIColor(Color.red).cgColor /* For iOS */
NSColor(Color.red).cgColor /* For macOS */
```

If you are looking for color components, you can find a helpful extensions [here in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62994482/5623035)

Also, check out **[How to convert UIColor to SwiftUI‘s Color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58605680/5623035)**

Comment: the core graphics seems to be wrong. Doing exactly that returns "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'CGColor' with an argument list of type '(Color)'"

Comment: `.cgColor` exists on `Color` from iOS 14.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color/cgcolor

Comment: .cgColor is marked deprecated and causes unexpected nil returns (at least on macOS 14.2.1).

Answer (score 34):

How about this solution?

```
extension Color {
 
    func uiColor() -> UIColor {

        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            return UIColor(self)
        }

        let components = self.components()
        return UIColor(red: components.r, green: components.g, blue: components.b, alpha: components.a)
    }

    private func components() -> (r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat, a: CGFloat) {

        let scanner = Scanner(string: self.description.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted))
        var hexNumber: UInt64 = 0
        var r: CGFloat = 0.0, g: CGFloat = 0.0, b: CGFloat = 0.0, a: CGFloat = 0.0

        let result = scanner.scanHexInt64(&hexNumber)
        if result {
            r = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0xff000000) >> 24) / 255
            g = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x00ff0000) >> 16) / 255
            b = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x0000ff00) >> 8) / 255
            a = CGFloat(hexNumber & 0x000000ff) / 255
        }
        return (r, g, b, a)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let uiColor = myColor.uiColor()
```

It's a bit of a hack, but it's at least something until we get a valid method for this. The key here is `self.description` which gives a hexadecimal description of the color (if it's not dynamic I should add). And the rest is just calculations to get the color components, and create a `UIColor`.

Comment: This may be hacky, but it's the correct answer in my opinion. There are definitely reasons for wanting to interrogate the Color type. For example, I have an extension on Color that returns an appropriate text color for the given Color as a background. When all I have to work with to begin with is the *var accentColor: Color*, then I need to be able to interrogate the makeup of that Color.

Upvoted for creativity alone and I hope that Apple has more to add to this next year.

Comment: NB: this does not work if you're referencing a color in an asset catalog (where `.description` yields `"NamedColor(name: \"Dark Roasts/Espresso100\", bundle: nil)"` or similar)

Comment: this does not work in case the color is `.red`, the `result` variable returns false in this case but I don't know why.

Comment: @JAHelia This is because `Color.red` is dynamic, i.e. it changes depending on the current mode. When dark mode is on, the red also gets darker. So it has no single value, that's why `result` returns false.

Comment: This isn't working. let components = self.components() always returns (0,0,0,0)

Answer (score 8):

Currently, this is not directly made available in the SwiftUI API. However, I managed to get a makeshift initializer working that utilizes debug prints and `dump`. I found that all of the other solutions failed to account for a `Color` initialized from a name, a bundle, the `.displayP3` color space, a `UIColor`, a static system `Color`, or any color whose opacity altered. My solution accounts for all of the aforementioned downfalls.

```swift
fileprivate struct ColorConversionError: Swift.Error {
    let reason: String
}

extension Color {

    @available(*, deprecated, message: "This is fragile and likely to break at some point. Hopefully it won't be required for long.")
    var uiColor: UIColor {
        do {
            return try convertToUIColor()
        } catch let error {
            assertionFailure((error as! ColorConversionError).reason)
            return .black
        }
    }
}

fileprivate extension Color {

    var stringRepresentation: String { description.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) }
    var internalType: String { "\(type(of: Mirror(reflecting: self).children.first!.value))".replacingOccurrences(of: "ColorBox<(.+)>", with: "$1", options: .regularExpression) }

    func convertToUIColor() throws -> UIColor  {
        if let color = try OpacityColor(color: self) {
            return try UIColor.from(swiftUIDescription: color.stringRepresentation, internalType: color.internalType).multiplyingAlphaComponent(by: color.opacityModifier)
        }
        return try UIColor.from(swiftUIDescription: stringRepresentation, internalType: internalType)
    }
}

fileprivate struct OpacityColor {

    let stringRepresentation: String
    let internalType: String
    let opacityModifier: CGFloat

    init(stringRepresentation: String, internalType: String, opacityModifier: CGFloat) {
        self.stringRepresentation = stringRepresentation
        self.internalType = internalType
        self.opacityModifier = opacityModifier
    }

    init?(color: Color) throws {
        guard color.internalType == "OpacityColor" else {
            return nil
        }
        let string = color.stringRepresentation

        let opacityRegex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: #"(\d+% )"#)
        let opacityLayerCount = opacityRegex.numberOfMatches(in: string, options: [], range: NSRange(string.startIndex..<string.endIndex, in: string))
        var dumpStr = ""
        dump(color, to: &dumpStr)
        dumpStr = dumpStr.replacingOccurrences(of: #"^(?:.*\n){\#(4 * opacityLayerCount)}.*?base: "#, with: "", options: .regularExpression)

        let opacityModifier = dumpStr.split(separator: "\n")
            .suffix(1)
            .lazy
            .map { $0.replacingOccurrences(of: #"\s+-\s+opacity: "#, with: "", options: .regularExpression) }
            .map { CGFloat(Double($0)!) }
            .reduce(1, *)

        let internalTypeRegex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: #"^.*\n.*ColorBox<.*?([A-Za-z0-9]+)>"#)
        let matches = internalTypeRegex.matches(in: dumpStr, options: [], range: NSRange(dumpStr.startIndex..<dumpStr.endIndex, in: dumpStr))
        guard let match = matches.first, matches.count == 1, match.numberOfRanges == 2 else {
            throw ColorConversionError(reason: "Could not parse internalType from \"\(dumpStr)\"")
            try! self.init(color: Color.black.opacity(1))
        }

        self.init(
            stringRepresentation: String(dumpStr.prefix { !$0.isNewline }),
            internalType: String(dumpStr[Range(match.range(at: 1), in: dumpStr)!]),
            opacityModifier: opacityModifier
        )
    }
}

fileprivate extension UIColor {

    static func from(swiftUIDescription description: String, internalType: String) throws -> UIColor {
        switch internalType {
        case "SystemColorType":
            guard let uiColor = UIColor.from(systemColorName: description) else {
                throw ColorConversionError(reason: "Could not parse SystemColorType from \"\(description)\"")
            }

            return uiColor

        case "_Resolved":
            guard description.range(of: "^#[0-9A-F]{8}$", options: .regularExpression) != nil else {
                throw ColorConversionError(reason: "Could not parse hex from \"\(description)\"")
            }

            let components = description
                .dropFirst()
                .chunks(of: 2)
                .compactMap { CGFloat.decimalFromHexPair(String($0)) }

            guard components.count == 4, let cgColor = CGColor(colorSpace: CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.linearSRGB)!, components: components) else {
                throw ColorConversionError(reason: "Could not parse hex from \"\(description)\"")
            }

            return UIColor(cgColor: cgColor)

        case "UIColor":
            let sections = description.split(separator: " ")
            let colorSpace = String(sections[0])
            let components = sections[1...]
                .compactMap { Double($0) }
                .map { CGFloat($0) }

            guard components.count == 4 else {
                throw ColorConversionError(reason: "Could not parse UIColor components from \"\(description)\"")
            }
            let (r, g, b, a) = (components[0], components[1], components[2], components[3])
            return try UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a, colorSpace: colorSpace)

        case "DisplayP3":
            let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: #"^DisplayP3\(red: (-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?), green: (-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?), blue: (-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?), opacity: (-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)"#)
            let matches = regex.matches(in: description, options: [], range: NSRange(description.startIndex..<description.endIndex, in: description))
            guard let match = matches.first, matches.count == 1, match.numberOfRanges == 5 else {
                throw ColorConversionError(reason: "Could not parse DisplayP3 from \"\(description)\"")
            }

            let components = (0..<match.numberOfRanges)
                .dropFirst()
                .map { Range(match.range(at: $0), in: description)! }
                .compactMap { Double(String(description[$0])) }
                .map { CGFloat($0) }

            guard components.count == 4 else {
                throw ColorConversionError(reason: "Could not parse DisplayP3 components from \"\(description)\"")
            }

            let (r, g, b, a) = (components[0], components[1], components[2], components[3])
            return UIColor(displayP3Red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)

        case "NamedColor":
            guard description.range(of: #"^NamedColor\(name: "(.*)", bundle: .*\)$"#, options: .regularExpression) != nil else {
                throw ColorConversionError(reason: "Could not parse NamedColor from \"\(description)\"")
            }

            let nameRegex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: #"name: "(.*)""#)
            let name = nameRegex.matches(in: description, options: [], range: NSRange(description.startIndex..<description.endIndex, in: description))
                .first
                .flatMap { Range($0.range(at: 1), in: description) }
                .map { String(description[$0]) }

            guard let colorName = name else {
                throw ColorConversionError(reason: "Could not parse NamedColor name from \"\(description)\"")
            }

            let bundleRegex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: #"bundle: .*NSBundle <(.*)>"#)
            let bundlePath = bundleRegex.matches(in: description, options: [], range: NSRange(description.startIndex..<description.endIndex, in: description))
                .first
                .flatMap { Range($0.range(at: 1), in: description) }
                .map { String(description[$0]) }
            let bundle =  bundlePath.map { Bundle(path: $0)! }

            return UIColor(named: colorName, in: bundle, compatibleWith: nil)!

        default:
            throw ColorConversionError(reason: "Unhandled type \"\(internalType)\"")
        }
    }

    static func from(systemColorName: String) -> UIColor? {
        switch systemColorName {
        case "clear": return .clear
        case "black": return .black
        case "white": return .white
        case "gray": return .systemGray
        case "red": return .systemRed
        case "green": return .systemGreen
        case "blue": return .systemBlue
        case "orange": return .systemOrange
        case "yellow": return .systemYellow
        case "pink": return .systemPink
        case "purple": return .systemPurple
        case "primary": return .label
        case "secondary": return .secondaryLabel
        default: return nil
        }
    }

    convenience init(red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat, colorSpace: String) throws {
        if colorSpace == "UIDisplayP3ColorSpace" {
            self.init(displayP3Red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
        } else if colorSpace == "UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace" {
            self.init(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
        } else if colorSpace == "kCGColorSpaceModelRGB" {
            let colorSpace = CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.linearSRGB)!
            let components = [red, green, blue, alpha]
            let cgColor = CGColor(colorSpace: colorSpace, components: components)!
            self.init(cgColor: cgColor)
        } else {
            throw ColorConversionError(reason: "Unhandled colorSpace \"\(colorSpace)\"")
        }
    }

    func multiplyingAlphaComponent(by multiplier: CGFloat?) -> UIColor {
        var a: CGFloat = 0
        getWhite(nil, alpha: &a)
        return withAlphaComponent(a * (multiplier ?? 1))
    }
}


// MARK: Helper extensions

extension StringProtocol {

    func chunks(of size: Int) -> [Self.SubSequence] {
        stride(from: 0, to: count, by: size).map {
            let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: $0)
            let end = index(start, offsetBy: size, limitedBy: endIndex) ?? endIndex
            return self[start..<end]
        }
    }
}

extension Int {

    init?(hexString: String) {
        self.init(hexString, radix: 16)
    }
}

extension FloatingPoint {

    static func decimalFromHexPair(_ hexPair: String) -> Self? {
        guard hexPair.count == 2, let value = Int(hexString: hexPair) else {
            return nil
        }
        return Self(value) / Self(255)
    }
}
```

**Note:** While this is not a long-term *solution* for the problem at hand since it hinges on the implementation details of `Color` which may change at some point, it should work in the interim for most, if not all colors.

Answer (score 7):

@turingtested Updated your answer to get rid of the long tuple crash.

```
extension Color {
    func uiColor() -> UIColor {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            return UIColor(self)
        }

        let scanner = Scanner(string: description.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted))
        var hexNumber: UInt64 = 0
        var r: CGFloat = 0.0, g: CGFloat = 0.0, b: CGFloat = 0.0, a: CGFloat = 0.0

        let result = scanner.scanHexInt64(&hexNumber)
        if result {
            r = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0xFF000000) >> 24) / 255
            g = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x00FF0000) >> 16) / 255
            b = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x0000FF00) >> 8) / 255
            a = CGFloat(hexNumber & 0x000000FF) / 255
        }
        return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
    }
}
```

Comment: this turns Color.white to UIColor.black )

Comment: This does not work on iOS 13.1

Answer (score 5):

**Xcode 15.2, Swift 5.9**

Since SwiftUI's `Color` is a struct, you can extend it with, for example, a static method.

```
extension Color {   
    static func convert(_ color: Color) -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(color)
    }
}
```

For macOS version, let's create a type method that returns `NSColor`.

```
extension Color {
    static func convert(_ color: Color) -> NSColor {
        return NSColor(color)
    }
}
```

Let's test this method on the BG color of the SpriteKit's scene.

```
import SwiftUI
import SpriteKit

struct ContentView : View {
    let scene = SKScene()
    
    init() {
        scene.backgroundColor = Color.convert(.secondary)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SpriteView(scene: scene)

            Rectangle()
                .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
        }
    }
}
```

It's obvious that two grey tints (Color vs UIColor) will be different.

Comment: Why a static function? Why not a normal instance method on Color?

Comment: Hi @HangarRash, what's wrong with a static function?

Comment: In this case it makes little sense to use a static method. Static methods should only be used when there's no existing instance involved. If you make it an instance method then you can easily call the `convert` method directly on a `Color` instance. `let someUIColor = someColor.convert()`.

Answer (score -1):

Correct method to create custom UIcolor with color set

```
init() {
    UISegmentedControl.appearance().selectedSegmentTintColor = UIColor.init(Color("orange"));       
    UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.black], for: .normal)
    UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.white], for: .selected)
}
```

Answer (score -4):

This is not how SwiftUI works. What you are trying to do is very UIKit like. In SwiftUI you rarely interrogate a view for any parameter. At this time, `Color` does not have any method or properties that return its RGB values. And I doubt there will ever be.

In general, with SwiftUI you need to go to the source, that is, the variable you used to create the color in the first place. For example:

```swift
  let r = 0.9
  let g = 0.4
  let b = 0.7
  let mycolor = Color(red: r, green: g, b, opacity: o)
```

**There is nothing like this:**

```swift
let green = mycolor.greenComponent()
```

Instead, you need to check variable `g` (the variable you used to create the color):

```swift
let green = g
```

I know it sounds odd, but that's how the framework has been designed. It may take time to get use to it, but you eventually will.

You may ask, but what if mycolor was created as:

```swift
let mycolor = Color.red
```

In that particular case, you are out of luck :-(

Comment: Hmm, so I have the colors of my app change dynamically from a store that returns only Color objects. So even though the solution I tried doesn't work, is there another way to change the tintColor fo the UINavigationBar to the dynamic Color value?

Comment: UINavigationBar is UIKit. You need to wait until SwiftUI _itself_ provides access to the navigation bar.