# How to compare three Color in SwiftUI

Tags: if-statement, swiftui, equatable

I have three Colors and I want to compare them. Should I make Color conform to Equatable protocol?

Code :

```
if Color.red == Color.green == Color.blue  {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: I don't see much sense in that snapshot, would you provide more context?

Comment: sorry it was editing mistake

Comment: I have added double Equals to second one

Comment: You can't ([without a hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58531033/968155)) extract RGB values from a `Color` in order to compare, like you could with `UIColor`. I would also say, that if you feel like you need to do it, you might have a bigger design problem

Comment: I dont have design problem I have game where I need to compare color of cards

Comment: If you're designing for swiftui, you should be comparing the data from which the `Color` is instantiated - not the `Color` instance itself

Comment: Ok thanks so Should I use enum with Color with case red , green, blue  in model?

Comment: Depends on what your needs are. Your data could also be the rgb components, but if you just have 3 types of colors, an enum could work too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really dont undestand what you want to achieve but you can compare them like

```
        let colorr = UIColor(red: 122/255, green: 100/255, blue: 180/255, alpha: 1.0)
        let rgbColorr = colorr.cgColor
        let rgbColorrs = rgbColorr.components
```

This `rgbColorrs` prints and array like `[0.47843137254901963, 0.39215686274509803, 0.7058823529411765, 1.0]` its like `[red,green,blue,alpha]`

```
if rgbColorrs[0] == rgbColors[1] == rgbColors[2]{
  //....
}
```

Or if you want to compare equality

```
 if UIColor.red.isEqual(UIColor.green.isEqual(UIColor.blue)){
        ...
    }
```

Comment: will this work for Color also and not just UIColor?