# Cannot assign value of type 'Color' to type 'UIColor'

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When I set `textField.textColor = Color.primary` inside `UITextViewWrapper` class give this error.

**How can I use primary color inside UITextViewWrapper? Is there any way to use it?**

```
fileprivate struct UITextViewWrapper: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = UITextView

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<UITextViewWrapper>) -> UITextView {
        let textField = UITextView()
        textField.textColor = Color.primary // here give error
        return textField
    }
          
 }
```

Comment: [`SwiftUI.Color`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color) != [`UIKit.UIColor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor). See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57257704/how-can-i-change-a-swiftui-color-to-uicolor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57257704/how-can-i-change-a-swiftui-color-to-uicolor).

Comment: Here, I wanted a solution to get a primary color that is not available in this solution. You can edit the question if there is anything missing. Thanks!

Comment: @Ashish I've provided the initializer for ios 14 and an alternative for lower versions in my solution below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On iOS 14+ you can use the new `UIColor` initializer.

```
textField.textColor = UIColor(Color.primary)
```

For lower versions, you can use:

```
textField.textColor = UIColor.label // gives the same result
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Extension UIColor:

   ```
   extension UIColor {
       class var primary: UIColor {
           return UIColor(named: "YourColorName")!
       }
   }
   ```
2. Usage:

   ```
   textField.textColor = .primary
   ```