# Cannot convert value of type 'Color' to expected argument type 'UIColor?'

Tags: ios, swiftui, navbar, uicolor

hello everyone i'm trying to make a navbar with a hexacedimal color in the asset file named "tint" but i have this error "Cannot convert value of type 'Color' to expected argument type 'UIColor?

```
.navigationBarColor(Color("tint"))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change a SwiftUI Color to UIColor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57257704/how-can-i-change-a-swiftui-color-to-uicolor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create new `UIColor` using that color

```
navigationBarColor(UIColor(Color("tint")))
```