# Hex codes/RGB values for SwiftUI colors?

Tags: swift, swiftui, hex, rgb

is there a compiled list of hex codes or RGB values for SwiftUI colors? I'd like to know either for Color.purple but can't seem to find any good sources. Is there a way to programmatically determine the hex code or RGB value? Or maybe I can look at some properties of Color? Thanks in advance!

Comment: We can create and use HEX or RGB colors in our codes, what is your goal now? do you want create or translate them together?

Comment: Translate default SwiftUI Color colors into RGB or hex...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are coding in SwiftUI 2 you can convert your Color to UIColor and use getRed method to get the red, green, blue and alpha components. Once you have the components you can convert the values to hexa string:

---

```
extension Color {
    var uiColor: UIColor { .init(self) }
    typealias RGBA = (red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat)
    var rgba: RGBA? {
        var (r, g, b, a): RGBA = (0, 0, 0, 0)
        return uiColor.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a) ? (r, g, b, a) : nil
    }
    var hexaRGB: String? {
        guard let (red, green, blue, _) = rgba else { return nil }
        return String(format: "#%02x%02x%02x",
            Int(red * 255),
            Int(green * 255),
            Int(blue * 255))
    }
    var hexaRGBA: String? {
        guard let (red, green, blue, alpha) = rgba else { return nil }
        return String(format: "#%02x%02x%02x%02x",
            Int(red * 255),
            Int(green * 255),
            Int(blue * 255),
            Int(alpha * 255))
    }
}
```

---

```
Color.purple.hexaRGB     // "#af52de"
Color.purple.hexaRGBA    // "#af52deff"
if let (red, green, blue, alpha) = Color.purple.rgba {
    red   // 0.686274528503418
    green // 0.321568638086319
    blue  // 0.8705882430076599
    alpha // 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## iOS 17/ macOS 14

You can ask for resolving `Color` components **in the given environment**, because colors are different in different environments (for example in dark and light environments). In the following sample, I resolved it using the current environment of the used color.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.self) var environment
    @State private var color = Color.yellow
    @State private var components: Color.Resolved?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ColorPicker("Select your favorite color", selection: $color)

            if let components {
                Text("HEX: \(components.description)")
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .onChange(of: color, initial: true) { components = color.resolve(in: environment) }
    }
}
```

<sub>The code above has been written for iOS 17 beta 1 using Xcode 15 beta 1</sub>

---

<sub>You can also [**get the RGBA components**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62994482/5623035) of the `Color`</sub>

Answer (score -2):

Isn't it good to use it like this?

```
    import UIKit

extension UIColor {
    
    convenience init(hex:Int, alpha: CGFloat = 1.0) {
        self.init(
            red:   CGFloat((hex & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat((hex & 0x00FF00) >> 8)  / 255.0,
            blue:  CGFloat((hex & 0x0000FF) >> 0)  / 255.0,
            alpha: alpha
        )
    }
    
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged as SwiftUI. It uses `Color` not `UIColor`