# How can I export RGB components of the ColorPicker view of SwiftUI 2?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, uicolor

I am using [this extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56586055/how-to-get-rgb-components-from-color-swiftui/62994482#62994482) to export RGB components of a [Color](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color) value which is changed when the user selects a color from the new [ColorPicker](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/colorpicker) view for SwiftUI 2:

I'm observing the value change for my color state like this:

```
@State private var textColor = Color.white

ColorPicker("Text Color", selection: $textColor, supportsOpacity: false)
            .onChange(of: textColor) { newColor in
              print(newColor.components)
            }
```

But, for some colors in the picker, when the value is printed, it has some negative values in it. What can cause this problem?

```
(red: 0.9607847332954407, green: 0.9254906177520752, blue: -9.62614990385191e-07, opacity: 1.0)
```

[image]

Comment: It is just approximately zero.

Comment: Just use a number formatter

Answer (score 3):

It's `scientific` representation of that very small number. (and seems like it overflowed)

it is actually:

```
-0.0000009626149903851910494267940521240234375 ≅ -0
```