# Re: Get pixel data as array from UIImage/CGImage in swift

Tags: swift, uiimage, rgb, bmp, cgimage

This code works for me (Swift 2 playground) in Gray scale, loading a colour .BMP image...

[Get pixel data as array from UIImage/CGImage in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768066/get-pixel-data-as-array-from-uiimage-cgimage-in-swift)

... but if I change `bytesPerPixel` to 3 (or 4) and use

```
let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
```

...the code still runs with no errors, but pixel values are all zeros. Any suggestions as to how to fix that?

Comment: Never mind what the other post says. Please post a link to the image you're starting with and show in full the actual code _you_ are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably forgot the CGImageAlphaInfo parameter. For color images, if you assume `bytesPerPixel` to be 4, you need to set either RGBA (or ARGB) when creating the context. Following is an example for RGBA without the alpha channel.

```
// RGBA format
let ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(&data, pixelsWide, pixelsHigh, 8,   
    bitmapBytesPerRow, colorSpace, CGImageAlphaInfo.NoneSkipLast.rawValue)
```

According to the documentation, you have these options:

```
enum CGImageAlphaInfo : UInt32 {
    case None
    case PremultipliedLast
    case PremultipliedFirst
    case Last
    case First
    case NoneSkipLast
    case NoneSkipFirst
    case Only
}
```

Comment: Thanks megakilo. I knew alpha was the problem and I had found the parameters, but wasn't aware of the crucial .rawvalue! :-)