# How to get 2d intensity array from a UIImage/CGImage in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, cgimage

I have followed the instructions from (just to name a few):
[How to get pixel data from a UIImage (Cocoa Touch) or CGImage (Core Graphics)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics)
[Re: Get pixel data as array from UIImage/CGImage in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944602/re-get-pixel-data-as-array-from-uiimage-cgimage-in-swift)
[Get pixel data as array from UIImage/CGImage in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768066/get-pixel-data-as-array-from-uiimage-cgimage-in-swift)

My problem is that in some cases, when trying to get pixel values for a 100x100 PNG image, the pixels come out wrong. For example, getting an image from a bitmap taken from the same image by using the CGContext yields these results:

[image]

[image]