# Convert UIImage to UInt8 Array in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, image

all!

I've been doing a lot of research into this and I've integrated several different solutions into my project, but none of them seem to work. My current solution has been borrowed from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768066/get-pixel-data-as-array-from-uiimage-cgimage-in-swift).

When I run my code, however, two things happen:

1. The pixel array remains initialized but unpopulated (Full of 0s)
2. I get two errors:

   CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination: set CGBITMAP_CONTEXT_LOG_ERRORS environmental variable to see the details

and

```
CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set
```

Any ideas? Here is my current built function that I'm calling for my Image class:

```
init?(fromImage image: UIImage!) {
    let imageRef = image!.CGImage
    self.width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef)
    self.height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef)
    let colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bytesPerRow = (4 * width);
    let bitsPerComponent :UInt = 8
    let pixels = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(malloc(width*height*4))

    var context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, width, height, Int(bitsPerComponent), bytesPerRow, colorspace, 0);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGFloat(width), CGFloat(height)), imageRef)
```

Any pointers would help a lot, as I'm new to understanding how all of this CGBitmap stuff works.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: First step would be to remove the implicitly unwrapped and force unwrapped `Optional`. They are just asking for runtime crashes and errors. It's much better to check an `Optional` and properly handle each case.

Comment: Great point. I'll get to that right away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not pass an `0` as the `bitmapInfo` param for `CGBitmapContextCreate`. For RGBA you shall pass `CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue`.

---

Supported combinations of `bitsPerComponent`, `bytesPerRow`, `colorspace` and `bitmapInfo` can be found here:
 https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-BCIBHHBB

*Note that **32 bits per pixel (bpp)** is **4 bytes per pixel** and you use it to calculate `bytesPerRow`*

---

Comment: This definitely helped a ton for getting the array populated, although I'm not sure it's being populated correctly. When I convert it back into an image straight away, the channels seems very messed up. Should I continue this here or start another question?

Answer (score -1):

You need to convert the image to NSData and then convert NSData
to UInt8 array.

```
let data: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)

// or let data: NSData = UIImageJPGRepresentation(image)

let count = data.length / sizeof(UInt8)

// create an array of Uint8
var array = [UInt8](count: count, repeatedValue: 0)

// copy bytes into array
data.getBytes(&array, length:count * sizeof(UInt8))
```

Comment: That would give you the PNG representation, not the raw pixel data.