# Swift: Filter every 4th item from array

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm

I'm trying to implement an image algorithm that iterates the byte array of the image.

(I'm trying to replicate this in Swift... https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Percentage_difference_between_images#JavaScript)

However, I need to ignore the alpha byte.

I was trying to be clever about it but got to the point where I can no longer remove the 4th items from the arrays of bytes.

Is there an easy way of doing that?

```
func compareImages(image1: UIImage, image2: UIImage) -> Double {
    // get data from images
    guard let data1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1, 1),
        let data2 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image2, 1) else {
            return -1
    }

    // zip up byte arrays
    return zip([UInt8](data1), [UInt8](data2))
        // sum the difference of the bytes divided by 255
        .reduce(0.0) { $0 + Double(abs(Int32($1.0) - Int32($1.1))) / 255.0 }
        // divide by the number of rbg bytes
        / Double(image1.size.width * image1.size.height * 3)
}
```

This would do exactly what I needed if I was able to remove/ignore the 4th bytes from each array?

The other option is to stride the arrays 4 at a time like it does in the Javascript example linked to but I felt I preferred this method. :)

Comment: I would advise against using a sentinel return of -1 in the case of failure – you should use an optional and return `nil` instead.

Comment: @Hamish yes, I agree. Will update, thanks :D

Comment: FYI - `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` does not return a simple stream of RGB values. It contains all kinds of meta data and the data of the image in a compressed, lossy format.

Comment: @rmaddy ah, ok. Will have to look at another way of doing it then. Thanks :D OK, going to need another run at this later I think. LOL! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image data can be large, therefore I would  avoid creating
intermediate arrays only to remove each 4th element.

Your `zip` + `reduce` approach can be combined with `enumerated()`
so that every 4th byte is ignored in the summation:

```
func rgbdiff(data1: [UInt8], data2: [UInt8], width: Int, height: Int) -> Double {
    return zip(data1, data2).enumerated().reduce(0.0) {
        $1.offset % 4 == 3 ? $0 : $0 + abs(Double($1.element.0) - Double($1.element.1))/255.0
    } / Double(width * height * 3)
}
```

Here it is assumed that `data1` and `data2` are arrays with the
RGBA pixel data and both images have the same dimensions.

You could also work on `Data` values without conversion to arrays:

```
func rgbdiff(data1: Data, data2: Data, width: Int, height: Int) -> Double {
      // ... same function ...
}
```

because the Swift 3 `Data`  is an `Iterator` of its bytes.

Comment: Ah, ok. Yeah makes sense. Use the enumerated version to reduce and filter at the same time. Nice, thanks :D Will take a look at using the Data directly but have to get the pixel data differently as rmaddy pointed out :) Thanks

Comment: OK, with over 1 million bytes in the array this reduces the number of times I have to go through it by quite a bit. Thanks :D

Answer (score 4):

i think you can remove alpha with this

1. enumerate to get pair (index, element)
2. filter to remove alpha
3. map to convert pair to only element

example code:

```
var array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

array = array.enumerated().filter { index, element in
    return index % 4 != 3
}.map { index, element in
    return element
}

print(array) // [0,1,2,4,5,6,8,9]
```

Comment: @Fogmeister Right, but i use `enumerate()` look for my edited answer

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3:

```
var array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

array = array.enumerated().flatMap { index, element in
    index % 4 != 3 ? element : nil
}

print(array) // [0,1,2,4,5,6,8,9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another, just a little bit more swifty way.

```
var foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
var bar = [Int]()

for i in stride(from: 0, to: foo.count - 3, by: 4) {
    bar += foo[i..<i+3]
}

bar //[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, for anyone who wants an update on filtering the array but also getting the correct pixel data...

I used a version of the answer from here... [Get pixel data as array from UIImage/CGImage in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768066/get-pixel-data-as-array-from-uiimage-cgimage-in-swift)

And @MartinR's answer to create the following two functions...

```
func pixelValues(fromCGImage imageRef: CGImage?) -> [UInt8]?
{
    var width = 0
    var height = 0
    var pixelValues: [UInt8]?

    if let imageRef = imageRef {
        width = imageRef.width
        height = imageRef.height
        let bitsPerComponent = imageRef.bitsPerComponent
        let bytesPerRow = imageRef.bytesPerRow
        let totalBytes = height * bytesPerRow
        let bitmapInfo = imageRef.bitmapInfo

        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        var intensities = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: totalBytes)

        let contextRef = CGContext(data: &intensities, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)
        contextRef?.draw(imageRef, in: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: CGFloat(width), height: CGFloat(height)))

        pixelValues = intensities
    }

    return pixelValues
}

func compareImages(image1: UIImage, image2: UIImage) -> Double? {
    guard let data1 = pixelValues(fromCGImage: image1.cgImage),
        let data2 = pixelValues(fromCGImage: image2.cgImage),
        data1.count == data2.count else {
            return nil
    }

    let width = Double(image1.size.width)
    let height = Double(image1.size.height)

    return zip(data1, data2)
        .enumerated()
        .reduce(0.0) {
            $1.offset % 4 == 3 ? $0 : $0 + abs(Double($1.element.0) - Double($1.element.1))
        }
        * 100 / (width * height * 3.0) / 255.0
}
```

I will be submitting this to the Rosetta website as soon as I work out how.

Answer (score 0):

```
let array1 = [1, 2, 3, 255, 5, 6, 7, 255, 8, 9, 10, 255]
let array2 = [1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 6, 7, 0, 8, 9, 10, 0]

let difference = zip(array1, array2)                   // Make one sequence from two arrays
    .enumerated()                                      // Assign each pair an index
    .filter({ $0.offset % 4 != 3 })                    // Strip away each 4th pair
    .map({ $0.element })                               // Discard indices
    .reduce(0, { $0 + Swift.abs($1.0 - $1.1) }) / 255  // Do the math

print(difference) // 0
```

Just make sure that both arrays have equal count of elements.

Comment: That's what I am doing. Just needed the filter in there. Thanks