# In iOS, how to draw the slider knob's background color chaning with the slider's gradient background color?

Tags: ios, objective-c, slider, gradient

[image]

Now we have a circular slider whose background color is gradient (mixed with hex color value of "00DBDB" and "FFC800"), I have already drawn the circular slider, the problem is how shoud I do to change the knob color to make its background color nearly same with its color at different slider's point? I have also searched google but got nothing useful information. Any one can help?

Comment: Any chance your slider is or can be open sourced?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks the powerful StackOverflow and its professional users, I found the answer to the question at  [Find color at point between two colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032562/ios-find-color-at-point-between-two-colors/) and [Calculate the color at a given point on a gradient between two colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22218140/calculate-the-color-at-a-given-point-on-a-gradient-between-two-colors)

The complete code is :

```
@implementation UIColor (Percentage)
```

`+ (UIColor *)colorFromStartColor:(UIColor *)startColor endColor:(UIColor *)endColor ofPercentage:(CGFloat)percentage {
    UIColor *resultColor;

    percentage = MAX(0.0, MIN(percentage, 1.0));

    CGFloat startRed, startBlue, startGreen, startAlpha;
    CGFloat endRed, endBlue, endGreen, endAlpha;
    [startColor getRed:&startRed green:&startGreen blue:&startBlue alpha:&startAlpha];
    [endColor getRed:&endRed green:&endGreen blue:&endBlue alpha:&endAlpha];

    CGFloat resultRed, resultBlue, resultGreen;
    resultRed = startRed + percentage * (endRed - startRed);
    resultGreen = startGreen + percentage * (endGreen - startGreen);
    resultBlue = startBlue + percentage * (endBlue - startBlue);

    resultColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:resultRed green:resultGreen blue:resultBlue alpha:1.0];
    return resultColor;

}

@end`