# Get lighter and darker color variations for a given UIColor

Tags: ios, swift, colors, core-graphics, uicolor

How to get different lighter and darker variations of a given UIColor in Swift?

[image]

Comment: title question is pretty trivial and allow different solutions; also you can use one function instead two using negative input parameter

Comment: Various techniques were proposed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598043/get-slightly-lighter-and-darker-color-from-uicolor, there are also answers in Swift.

Comment: @ShadowOf updated, thanks for input

Comment: **Swift - 4.0** [Click hare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46729248/7245216) for answer

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35950131/6059640) was already available at the time you posted your question. In general, I think this question and the other are very similar, if not duplicated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Slightly Lighter and Darker Color from UIColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598043/get-slightly-lighter-and-darker-color-from-uicolor)

Answer (score 179, accepted):

### Updated

Use below **UIColor Extension:**

```
extension UIColor {

    func lighter(by percentage: CGFloat = 30.0) -> UIColor? {
        return self.adjust(by: abs(percentage) )
    }

    func darker(by percentage: CGFloat = 30.0) -> UIColor? {
        return self.adjust(by: -1 * abs(percentage) )
    }

    func adjust(by percentage: CGFloat = 30.0) -> UIColor? {
        var red: CGFloat = 0, green: CGFloat = 0, blue: CGFloat = 0, alpha: CGFloat = 0
        if self.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha) {
            return UIColor(red: min(red + percentage/100, 1.0),
                           green: min(green + percentage/100, 1.0),
                           blue: min(blue + percentage/100, 1.0),
                           alpha: alpha)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let color = UIColor(red:0.96, green:0.54, blue:0.10, alpha:1.0)
color.lighter(30) // returns lighter color by 30%
color.darker(30) // returns darker color by 30%
```

instead of `.lighter()` and `.darker()`, you can use `.adjust()` with positive values for lightening and negative values for darkening

```
color.adjust(-30) // 30% darker color
color.adjust(30) // 30% lighter color
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: You modify all components by the same value instead of changing them proportionally. See how orange becomes yellow when you make it lighter.

Comment: Adding values proportionally isn't correct. try this color UIColor(red:0.89, green:0.28, blue:0.00, alpha:1.0)

Comment: But adding the same value to all components isn't correct either, it changes the color. Have a look at the various answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598043/get-slightly-lighter-and-darker-color-from-uicolor  where the *brightness* in the HSB representation is adjusted.

Comment: @MartinR I have executed your function and mine, both outputs are same(orange did not become yellow ;-) ). However i need to improve skill to reduce the code.
i should have avoided converting to RGB values and write logic in single function. will update the code

Comment: I believe for black color lighter , returns green color

Comment: What does the `=30.0` mean in the function declaration `func ...(by percentage:CGFloat=30.0)`

Comment: @Codey you probably know by now, but = sets the default value for it.

Comment: Works like charm

Comment: For anyone this fails for for dark colours... it produces negative values when used to darken, which seems fine in some cases but in other cases displays as bright for that colour - e.g. UIColor.brown.darker(), which ends up as RGB 0.3 0.1 -0.1, is displaying as royal blue in SKShapeNode's fillColor. To fix, add max(x, 0) checks, e.g. "blue: max(min(blue + percentage/100, 1.0), 0.0)"

Comment: This is an example of an answer on SO with many votes which is very wrong in many ways.  (To adjust the brightness of a color in iOS you just ................ adjust the `. brightness` . )

Comment: Despite the update, this answer is still wrong.

Answer (score 59):

I want to provide another version using brightness & saturation instead of RGB

```
extension UIColor {
  /**
   Create a lighter color
   */
  func lighter(by percentage: CGFloat = 30.0) -> UIColor {
    return self.adjustBrightness(by: abs(percentage))
  }
  
  /**
   Create a darker color
   */
  func darker(by percentage: CGFloat = 30.0) -> UIColor {
    return self.adjustBrightness(by: -abs(percentage))
  }
  
  /**
   Try to increase brightness or decrease saturation
   */
  func adjustBrightness(by percentage: CGFloat = 30.0) -> UIColor {
    var h: CGFloat = 0, s: CGFloat = 0, b: CGFloat = 0, a: CGFloat = 0
    if self.getHue(&h, saturation: &s, brightness: &b, alpha: &a) {
      if b < 1.0 {
        let newB: CGFloat = max(min(b + (percentage/100.0)*b, 1.0), 0.0)
        return UIColor(hue: h, saturation: s, brightness: newB, alpha: a)
      } else {
        let newS: CGFloat = min(max(s - (percentage/100.0)*s, 0.0), 1.0)
        return UIColor(hue: h, saturation: newS, brightness: b, alpha: a)
      }
    }
    return self
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is better than modifying the RGB values

Comment: Don't think this works when saturation is 0 and brightness is 1.0.  IE white.  In this case you end up with unchanged saturation.

Comment: (You cannot brighten white.)  This is the correct approach. The RGB answers are totally incorrect on many levels.

Comment: But you can darken white (it should turn gray) but this does not do that :/

Answer (score 22):

#### ✅ Both UIKit & AppKit: 'aka' UIColor & NSColor

With this method, you can mix colors in any platform with any color. In this case `black` for darker and `white` for lighter appearance:

```
#if canImport(UIKit)
public typealias NativeColor = UIColor
#elseif canImport(AppKit)
public typealias NativeColor = NSColor
#endif

public extension NativeColor {
    func mix(with target: NativeColor, amount: CGFloat) -> Self {
        var r1: CGFloat = 0, g1: CGFloat = 0, b1: CGFloat = 0, a1: CGFloat = 0
        var r2: CGFloat = 0, g2: CGFloat = 0, b2: CGFloat = 0, a2: CGFloat = 0

        getRed(&r1, green: &g1, blue: &b1, alpha: &a1)
        target.getRed(&r2, green: &g2, blue: &b2, alpha: &a2)

        return Self(
            red: r1 * (1.0 - amount) + r2 * amount,
            green: g1 * (1.0 - amount) + g2 * amount,
            blue: b1 * (1.0 - amount) + b2 * amount,
            alpha: a1
        )
    }

    func lighter(by amount: CGFloat = 0.2) -> Self { mix(with: .white, amount: amount) }
    func darker(by amount: CGFloat = 0.2) -> Self { mix(with: .black, amount: amount) }
}
```

---

###### SwiftUI: Color - iOS 14 / macOS 10.16

<sub>⚠️ Requires previous extension</sub>

```
extension Color {
    public func lighter(by amount: CGFloat = 0.2) -> Self { Self(NativeColor(self).lighter(by: amount)) }
    public func darker(by amount: CGFloat = 0.2) -> Self { Self(NativeColor(self).darker(by: amount)) }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Since I use SwiftUI in my current project, I adapted the best answer from Stephen.
Tested with Xcode 12.0, SwiftUI 2 and iOS 14.0

```
extension Color {
    var components: (red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, opacity: CGFloat) {
        #if canImport(UIKit)
        typealias NativeColor = UIColor
        #elseif canImport(AppKit)
        typealias NativeColor = NSColor
        #endif

        var r: CGFloat = 0
        var g: CGFloat = 0
        var b: CGFloat = 0
        var o: CGFloat = 0

        guard NativeColor(self).getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &o) else {
            return (0, 0, 0, 0)
        }
        return (r, g, b, o)
    }
    
    func lighter(by percentage: CGFloat = 30.0) -> Color {
        return self.adjust(by: abs(percentage) )
    }

    func darker(by percentage: CGFloat = 30.0) -> Color {
        return self.adjust(by: -1 * abs(percentage) )
    }

    func adjust(by percentage: CGFloat = 30.0) -> Color {
        return Color(red: min(Double(self.components.red + percentage/100), 1.0),
                     green: min(Double(self.components.green + percentage/100), 1.0),
                     blue: min(Double(self.components.blue + percentage/100), 1.0),
                     opacity: Double(self.components.opacity))
    }
}
```

Comment: getRed does not return a Bool on macOS

Answer (score 14):

## PLS NOTE TWO CRITICAL COLOR TIPS BELOW...

#### Simple modern solution

```
extension UIColor {
    ///Take a color and return a "somewhat darker" color
    var darker: UIColor {
        var h: CGFloat = 0, s: CGFloat = 0, b: CGFloat = 0, a: CGFloat = 0
        guard self.getHue(&h, saturation: &s, brightness: &b, alpha: &a) else {
            print("** OS problem")
            return self
        }
        let nudged = b * 0.5
        return UIColor(hue: h, saturation: s, brightness: nudged, alpha: a)
    }
}
```

usage `something.color = .yellow.darker`

It's that easy.

As explained by @MarkA.Donohoe, if you prefer a function the correct naming in UIKit would be:

```
 .adjustingBrightness(byMultiplier f: CGFloat)
```

ie, `let nudged = b * f`

Save you typing:

```
extension UIColor {
    ///Take a color and return a "somewhat darker" color
    var darker: UIColor {
        var h: CGFloat = 0, s: CGFloat = 0, b: CGFloat = 0, a: CGFloat = 0
        guard self.getHue(&h, saturation: &s, brightness: &b, alpha: &a) else {
            print("** OS problem")
            return self
        }
        let nudged = b * 0.5
        return UIColor(hue: h, saturation: s, brightness: nudged, alpha: a)
    }
    
    ///Adjust color with UIKit style function naming :)
    func adjustingBrightness(byMultiplier: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
        var h: CGFloat = 0, s: CGFloat = 0, b: CGFloat = 0, a: CGFloat = 0
        guard self.getHue(&h, saturation: &s, brightness: &b, alpha: &a) else {
            print("** OS problem")
            return self
        }
        print(">>", h, s, b, a)
        let nudged = b + ( (1.0 - b) * byMultiplier )
        print(">> NEW B", nudged)
        return UIColor(hue: h, saturation: s, brightness: nudged, alpha: a)
    }
}
```

## TIP 1

Note that when dealing with modern UIKit colors you almost always want something like

```
c = UIColor.label.resolvedColor(with: .current).adjusting ...etc
```

rather than

```
c = UIColor.label.adjusting ... etc
```

Google as needed.

## TIP 2

Talk to your color designers, adjusting colors is not so easy conceptually. (How do you make black "brighter"? Who knows.)

**Here's what you *typically want* in many or most cases** when you want to "lighten up / brighten up" a color:

```
///Example. Original b is 0.2.  Hence 0.8 "remaining". Pass in a fraction of 0.5. Half of 0.8 is 0.4, so result is 0.6
func adjustingBrightness(byFractionallyIncreasingTowardsOne fito: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
    var h: CGFloat = 0, s: CGFloat = 0, b: CGFloat = 0, a: CGFloat = 0
    guard self.getHue(&h, saturation: &s, brightness: &b, alpha: &a) else {
        print("** OS problem")
        return self
    }
    print(">>", h, s, b, a)
    let nudged = b + ( (1.0 - b) * fito )
    print(">> NEW B", nudged)
    return UIColor(hue: h, saturation: s, brightness: nudged, alpha: a)
}
```

Comment: With the exception of `withBrightnessComponent(_ brightness: CGFloat)`, the others all modify an existing value rather than replacing it. As such, and following Apple's API design guidelines, consider these alternative names... `.adjustingBrightness(byPercent percent: CGFloat)` and `.adjustingBrightness(byFactor factor: CGFloat)`

Answer (score 4):

**For Swift 5.0 :**

```
extension UIColor {

func lighter(by percentage: CGFloat = 10.0) -> UIColor {
    return self.adjust(by: abs(percentage))
}

func darker(by percentage: CGFloat = 10.0) -> UIColor {
    return self.adjust(by: -abs(percentage))
}

func adjust(by percentage: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
    var alpha, hue, saturation, brightness, red, green, blue, white : CGFloat
    (alpha, hue, saturation, brightness, red, green, blue, white) = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

    let multiplier = percentage / 100.0

    if self.getHue(&hue, saturation: &saturation, brightness: &brightness, alpha: &alpha) {
        let newBrightness: CGFloat = max(min(brightness + multiplier*brightness, 1.0), 0.0)
        return UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: saturation, brightness: newBrightness, alpha: alpha)
    }
    else if self.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha) {
        let newRed: CGFloat = min(max(red + multiplier*red, 0.0), 1.0)
        let newGreen: CGFloat = min(max(green + multiplier*green, 0.0), 1.0)
        let newBlue: CGFloat = min(max(blue + multiplier*blue, 0.0), 1.0)
        return UIColor(red: newRed, green: newGreen, blue: newBlue, alpha: alpha)
    }
    else if self.getWhite(&white, alpha: &alpha) {
        let newWhite: CGFloat = (white + multiplier*white)
        return UIColor(white: newWhite, alpha: alpha)
    }

    return self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Kenji-Tran's answer works fine, as long as your starting color is not black (brightness value 0). With the addition of a few lines of extra code, you can also make black "lighter" (i.e. brighten it to a grayscale or color value).

**Note:** I wasn't able to add this change using an Edit and I'm not allowed to comment on Kenji-Tran's answer due to my "new boy" rep, therefore I found no other way to share my knowledge on SO then by posting a new answer. I hope that's okay.

```
extension UIColor {
  /**
   Create a ligher color
   */
  func lighter(by percentage: CGFloat = 30.0) -> UIColor {
    return self.adjustBrightness(by: abs(percentage))
  }

  /**
   Create a darker color
   */
  func darker(by percentage: CGFloat = 30.0) -> UIColor {
    return self.adjustBrightness(by: -abs(percentage))
  }

  /**
   Try to increase brightness or decrease saturation
   */
  func adjustBrightness(by percentage: CGFloat = 30.0) -> UIColor {
    var h: CGFloat = 0, s: CGFloat = 0, b: CGFloat = 0, a: CGFloat = 0
    if self.getHue(&h, saturation: &s, brightness: &b, alpha: &a) {
      if b < 1.0 {
        /**
         Below is the new part, which makes the code work with black as well as colors
        */
        let newB: CGFloat
        if b == 0.0 {
            newB = max(min(b + percentage/100, 1.0), 0.0)
        } else {
            newB = max(min(b + (percentage/100.0)*b, 1.0), 0,0)
        }
        return UIColor(hue: h, saturation: s, brightness: newB, alpha: a)
      } else {
        let newS: CGFloat = min(max(s - (percentage/100.0)*s, 0.0), 1.0)
        return UIColor(hue: h, saturation: newS, brightness: b, alpha: a)
      }
    }
    return self
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing case (y). May I ask a question? Why it is `b == 0.0 && s == 0.0`? I thought just want more case `b == 0` is enough to solve the issue. Because if `b is 0 and s > 0`, your code still not be able to make the color ligher?

Comment: Good question. It's a mistake. I have fixed the code. The reason I checked if `s == 0` was because I wanted it to work for black to grayscale. But obviously, without the `s == 0` it works for any color with brightness zero. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**Version with RGB values modification**

Here I put simple `UIColor` extension which is based on previous answers. It's working perfectly for me.

Below demo:

[image: Colors demo]

**Colors manipulation code**

```
public extension UIColor {

    /**
     Create a lighter color
     */
    public func lighter(by percentage: CGFloat = 30.0) -> UIColor {
        return self.adjustBrightness(by: abs(percentage))
    }

    /**
     Create a darker color
     */
    public func darker(by percentage: CGFloat = 30.0) -> UIColor {
        return self.adjustBrightness(by: -abs(percentage))
    }

    /**
     Changing R, G, B values
     */

    func adjustBrightness(by percentage: CGFloat = 30.0) -> UIColor {

        var red: CGFloat = 0.0
        var green: CGFloat = 0.0
        var blue: CGFloat = 0.0
        var alpha: CGFloat = 0.0

        if self.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha) {

            let pFactor = (100.0 + percentage) / 100.0

            let newRed = (red*pFactor).clamped(to: 0.0 ... 1.0)
            let newGreen = (green*pFactor).clamped(to: 0.0 ... 1.0)
            let newBlue = (blue*pFactor).clamped(to: 0.0 ... 1.0)

            return UIColor(red: newRed, green: newGreen, blue: newBlue, alpha: alpha)
        }

        return self
    }
}
```

**Clamped function**
Extension to easily keep values between min and max.

```
extension Comparable {

    func clamped(to range: ClosedRange<Self>) -> Self {

        if self > range.upperBound {
            return range.upperBound
        } else if self < range.lowerBound {
            return range.lowerBound
        } else {
            return self
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4 version that supports RGBA, HSBA, and WB (greyscale)**

Here's a variation of TranQuan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42381754/522498) that also supports greyscale colors like `.white` and `.black`. (Note: I removed saturation adjustment because I didn't think it belonged in a simple function like this.)

```
extension UIColor {
    /**
     Create a ligher color
     */
    func lighter(by percentage: CGFloat = 10.0) -> UIColor {
        return self.adjustBrightness(by: abs(percentage))
    }

    /**
     Create a darker color
     */
    func darker(by percentage: CGFloat = 10.0) -> UIColor {
        return self.adjustBrightness(by: -abs(percentage))
    }

    /**
     Try to adjust brightness and falls back to adjusting colors if necessary
     */
    func adjustBrightness(by percentage: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
        var alpha, hue, saturation, brightness, red, green, blue, white : CGFloat
        (alpha, hue, saturation, brightness, red, green, blue, white) = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

        let multiplier = percentage / 100.0

        if self.getHue(&hue, saturation: &saturation, brightness: &brightness, alpha: &alpha) {
            let newBrightness: CGFloat = max(min(brightness + multiplier*brightness, 1.0), 0.0)
            return UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: saturation, brightness: newBrightness, alpha: alpha)
        }
        else if self.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha) {
            let newRed: CGFloat = min(max(red + multiplier*red, 0.0), 1.0)
            let newGreen: CGFloat = min(max(green + multiplier*green, 0.0), 1.0)
            let newBlue: CGFloat = min(max(blue + multiplier*blue, 0.0), 1.0)
            return UIColor(red: newRed, green: newGreen, blue: newBlue, alpha: alpha)
        }
        else if self.getWhite(&white, alpha: &alpha) {
            let newWhite: CGFloat = (white + multiplier*white)
            return UIColor(white: newWhite, alpha: alpha)
        }

        return self
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great, thank you!

Comment: I actually can't seem to brighten `.black` or really really dark gray, so as a workaround I created another function that takes a percentage and sets the color's brightness directly to that level. The issue is the formula: `brightness + multiplier * brightness`, this doesn't work when the brightness is 0 or really small.  So instead you can create a color like this `return UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: saturation, brightness: max(min(percentage / 100.0, 1.0), 0.0), alpha: alpha)`

Answer (score 1):

For `macOS` apps, there is an in-built function for color blending.

To make a color lighter, simply call

```
NSColor.systemRed.blended(withFraction: 0.35, of: .white)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using SwiftUI and was looking for a quick solution.

This method changes the alpha channel (0 is transparent, 1 is opaque) and puts it in front of a white color view, so you're actually mixing white with a color. Higher alpha value, more white mixed in = brighter.

Converting the `Color` to `UIColor`, modifying, and converting back does the job:

```swift
Color(UIColor(Color.blue).withAlphaComponent(0.5))
    .background(Color.white) // IMPORTANT: otherwise your view will be see-through
```

To darken a color change `Color.white` to `Color.black`

Answer (score 0):

Using lukszar clampled function, I wrote this function for the UIColor extension, using real proportions of RGB values. I hope it is helpful

```
public extension UIColor {

  public func lighter(by percentage: CGFloat = 30.0) -> UIColor {
    return self.adjustBrightness(by: abs(percentage))
  }

  public func darker(by percentage: CGFloat = 30.0) -> UIColor {
    return self.adjustBrightness(by: -abs(percentage))
  }

  func adjustBrightness(by percentage: CGFloat = 30.0) -> UIColor {

    let ratio = percentage/100

    var red:   CGFloat = 0.0
    var green: CGFloat = 0.0
    var blue:  CGFloat = 0.0
    var alpha: CGFloat = 0.0

    if self.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha) {
      let newRed =   (red   + ((ratio < 0) ? red   * ratio : (1 - red)   * ratio)).clamped(to: 0.0 ... 1.0)
      let newGreen = (green + ((ratio < 0) ? green * ratio : (1 - green) * ratio)).clamped(to: 0.0 ... 1.0)
      let newBlue =  (blue  + ((ratio < 0) ? blue  * ratio : (1 - blue)  * ratio)).clamped(to: 0.0 ... 1.0)
      return UIColor(red: newRed, green: newGreen, blue: newBlue, alpha: alpha)
    }
    return self
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The code example below demonstrate how you can get a lighter and darker shade of a given color, useful in applications having dynamic themes

**For Darker Color**

```
+ (UIColor *)darkerColorForColor:(UIColor *)c
{
CGFloat r, g, b, a;
    if ([c getRed:&r green:&g blue:&b alpha:&a])
return [UIColor colorWithRed:MAX(r - 0.2, 0.0)
                               green:MAX(g - 0.2, 0.0)
                                blue:MAX(b - 0.2, 0.0)
return nil; 
}
```

**For Lighter Color**

```
+ (UIColor *)lighterColorForColor:(UIColor *)c
{
CGFloat r, g, b, a;
    if ([c getRed:&r green:&g blue:&b alpha:&a])
return [UIColor colorWithRed:MIN(r + 0.2, 1.0)
                       green:MIN(g + 0.2, 1.0)
                        blue:MIN(b + 0.2, 1.0)
alpha:a];
return nil;
}
```