# Value of type 'UIColor' has no member 'adjust'

Tags: swift5, uicolor

I am trying to get a lighter version of a UIColor defined by user in my custom view like-

```
public var borderColor : UIColor?{ //needs to be set by user
   didSet{
       setNeedsLayout()
   }
}
private var backgroundColor : UIColor{ // computed property
     if let color = borderColor{
        return color.adjust(by: abs(20))
     }
}
```

I searched for possible solution and got this

> [Get lighter and darker color variations for a given UIColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38435308/get-lighter-and-darker-color-variations-for-a-given-uicolor)

However, I am getting a compile time error stating-

```
Value of type 'UIColor' has no member 'adjust'
```

Also in the Apple documentation of UIColor, I don't find any method named "adjust(by:)".

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: If you go back to the Q&A you linked to you will see that the accepted answer contains an *extension* to `UIColor` which adds `adjust(by:)`. Add that code to yours.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing that out. I totally missed it.