# How do you programmatically lighten or darken a dynamic Color in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, colors, swiftui, accessibility, contrast

Others have covered how to [lighten and darken UIColors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38435308/get-lighter-and-darker-color-variations-for-a-given-uicolor) in Swift, but I have not seen a good way to programmatically "lighten" and "darken" dynamic SwiftUI `Colors`.

I have green `Text` using `Color(.systemGreen)` that I would like to appear **darker on light backgrounds** and **lighter on dark backgrounds.**

- Using the `.contrast()` modifier increases the green's saturation but doesn't really make it darker.
- Using the `.brightness()` modifier with a negative makes it darker for both light and dark mode, which doesn't really work for dark mode since it's harder to read.

Comment: It might be best to just make a custom color set, in the assets catalog

Comment: Great question, did you ever end up solving this @NikPayne?

Answer (score 1):

You need to observe which color theme is set now and use specific color depends on it. If you want use non-system color, it's better add new Color Set in Assets for light and dark modes.

```
import SwiftUI
struct temp_color: View {
    var colorScheme: ColorScheme
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .light ? Color(.systemGreen) : Color(.systemRed))}
}
struct temp_color_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    temp_color(colorScheme: .light)
    }
}
```